# How do I change the mysql root password?

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, passwords

i have installed MYSQL on my linux from apache.Then i start MYSQL from this command:`sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root`.I changed the password using this command in mysql:

```
use mysql
UPDATE user
SET Password=PASSWORD('something')
WHERE user='root';
```

but when i exit from mysql and then enter it using the above command it does not asked me for password.And when i enter this command:`sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root --password=something` it gave me the error:`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
Phpmyadmin also works correctly without asking me any password!!!
How can i set the password correctly?

Comment: try to excute this `flush privileges;` after your update query.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use:

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

or

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass
```

if you have already got a password.

quoted from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/)

Comment: Be sure to have -p'password' and not -p 'password', there is no space between the param and the password